# FTP upload ProgressBar in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ftp, progress-bar, ftpwebrequest

I'm coding an application that uploads a file to a remote FTP server. This is my code that already works.

```
clsrequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

Dim bFile() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(rutaorigen)

Dim clsStream As System.IO.Stream = clsrequest.GetRequestStream()

clsStream.Write(bFile, 0, bFile.Length)

clsStream.Close()
clsStream.Dispose()
```

Now I want to show the progress in a `ProgressBar` in VB.NET.

Files are not too big (10 MB max).

I've already tried an example that I found here, but it didn't work.

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Which example did you try, and why didn't it work?

Comment: It was from YouTube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUyEHiJTkRg
It is like what i want to do but not exactly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got this from an example a long time ago. The code should be fairly easy to change for your needs.

```
Dim clsRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = _
        DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(ServLabel.Text & TextBox1.Text), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)

    clsRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(PassLabel.Text, UserLabel.Text)
    clsRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
    rfshTMR.Enabled = True
    Dim File() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(txtFile.Text)
    Dim clsStream As System.IO.Stream = _
        clsRequest.GetRequestStream()
    clsStream.Write(File, 0, File.Length)
    For offset As Integer = 0 To File.Length Step 1024
        ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = CType(offset * ToolStripProgressBar1.Maximum / File.Length, Integer)
        Dim chunkSize As Integer = File.Length - offset - 1
        If chunkSize > 1024 Then chunkSize = 1024
        clsStream.Write(File, offset, chunkSize)
        ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = ToolStripProgressBar1.Maximum
    Next
    clsStream.Close()
    clsStream.Dispose()
    MsgBox("File Is Now In Database", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Upload Complete")
```

Comment: Hello Guys, Still Cant Make It Work. Do I Need To Implement Multithreading? Thanks

Comment: This code works for me, make sure you have no obvious errors. And yes multi-threading is a good idea.

Comment: Why `ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = ToolStripProgressBar1.Maximum` is inside the loop? I think it should be outside and after the loop.

Comment: I think that's to finalize the progressbar at the end because if it was not in the loop and you were downloading multiple files it would not fill the progressbar to the top when you're files are completed uploading. Understand?

Answer (score 1):

Simple progress on console:

```
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip")
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

Using fileStream As Stream = File.OpenRead("C:\local\path\file.zip"),
      ftpStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(10240 - 1) {}
    Dim read As Integer
    Do
        read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        If read > 0 Then
            ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, read)
            Console.WriteLine("Uploaded {0} bytes", fileStream.Position)
        End If
    Loop While read > 0
End Using
```

---

WinForms GUI progress:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Run Upload on background thread
    Task.Run((Sub() Upload()))
End Sub

Sub Upload()
    Dim request As WebRequest =
        WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip")
    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

    Using fileStream As Stream = File.OpenRead("C:\local\path\file.zip"),
          ftpStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        ProgressBar1.Invoke(Sub() ProgressBar1.Maximum = fileStream.Length)
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(10240 - 1) {}
        Dim read As Integer
        Do
            read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            If read > 0 Then
                ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, read)
                ProgressBar1.Invoke(Sub() ProgressBar1.Value = fileStream.Position)
            End If
        Loop While read > 0
    End Using
End Sub
```

[image]